# How to provide non-technical users with better rspec output

Tags: documentation, rspec

When writing UI automation specs RSpec has a great option

```
--format=documentation
```

You can combine this with

```
--dry-run
```

and get instant tests as documentation...

The only problem is that it has all the technical details which are not understandable by business users.  This is unlike Cucumber where the business description and the technical details to complete those steps are separated.

How can I take the existing spec files and create 'better'(which I define as non-technical) user documentation without technical details?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shell script to produce more readable documentation:

```
find . -regex \
 '\(.*_spec\.rb\|spec_.*\.rb\)' ! -name 'spec_helper.rb' \
 -exec cat {} \; | \
grep -E \
'(^ +?describe |RSpec\.describe|^ +?it |^ +?expect|\.should)'|\
sed -E 's/ do +?$//' | # No need for the do \
sed 's/, order\: \:defined//' | # No need for order: :defined \
sed "s/\.value)/)/" | # No need for .value \
sed "s/ eq / equal /" | # Change 'eq' to 'equal' \
sed "s/ eq(/ equal (/" |
sed "s/).to_s/)/" | # No need for .to_s\
sed "s/.text)/)/" | # No need for .text \
sed "s/RSpec\.//" | # Remove Rspec. \
sed $'s/^describe /\\\ndescribe /' | # linefeed between specs \
sed "s/(page\./(/" | # No need for page. \
sed -E "s/find_by_id ?//" | # No need for find_by_id \
sed -E "s/\(\(/(/;s/\)\)/)/" | # Remove double parens ((and))  \
sed -E "s/\(find /(/" | # No need for find statements \
sed -E "s/\(p\./(/" | # No need for p. before page objects \
sed -E "s/have_css/have/" | # make have_css more readable \
sed -E "s/\.disabled\?\)\.to/.disabled\? to/" | # Fix parens \
sed -E $'s/enddescribe/end\\\n\\\ndescribe/' | # Fix issue \
sed '/^end$/d' | # Remove lines with just end on them \
sed '1d' # Remove first (blank) line
```